# How can auto-Incrementing be maintained when concurrent transactions occur on a compound key In MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, auto-increment, compound-key

I recently encountered an error in my application with concurrent transactions. Previously, auto-incrementing for compound key was implemented using the application itself using PHP. However, as I mentioned, the id got duplicated, and all sorts of issues happened which I painstakingly fixed manually afterward.

Now I have read about related issues and found suggestions to use trigger.

So I am planning on implementing a trigger somewhat like this.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER auto_increment_my_table
    BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            SET NEW.id = SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM my_table WHERE type = NEW.type;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But my doubt regarding concurrency still remains. Like what if this trigger was executed concurrently and both got the same MAX(id) when querying?

Is this the correct way to handle my issue or is there any better way?

Comment: *Is this the correct way to handle my issue or is there any better way?* No. Any method except built-in AUTO_INCREMENT is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue.

The answer was somewhat in the direction of [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67621380/12284292). But not quite exactly.

The way I solved it did indeed involved an additional table but not like the way He suggested.

I created an additional table to store meta data about transactions.

Eg: I had table_key like this

```
CREATE TABLE `journals` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trans_no` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `transaction` (`type`,`trans_no`)
)
```

So I created a meta_journals table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `meta_journals` (
  `type` smallint NOT NULL,
  `next_trans_no` bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type`),
)
```

and seeded it with all the different types of journals and the next sequence number.

And whenever I insert a new transaction to the `journals` I made sure to increment the `next_trans_no` of the corresponding `type` in the `meta_transactions` table. This increment operation is issued inside the same database `TRANSACTION`, i.e. inside the `BEGIN` AND `COMMIT`

This allowed me to use the exclusive lock acquired by the `UPDATE` statement on the row of `meta_journals` table. So when two insert statement is issued for the journal concurrently, One had to wait until the lock acquired by the other transaction is released by `COMMIT`ing.

Answer (score 1):

An example - how to solve autoincrementing in compound index.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test ( id INT,
>                     type VARCHAR(192),
>                     value INT,
>                     PRIMARY KEY (id, type) );
> ```

> ```
> -- create additional service table which will help
>
> CREATE TABLE test_sevice ( type VARCHAR(192),
>                            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                            PRIMARY KEY (type, id) ) ENGINE = MyISAM;
> ```

> ```
> -- create trigger which wil generate id value for new row
>
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_test_autoincrement
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON test
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     INSERT INTO test_sevice (type) VALUES (NEW.type);
>     SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
> END
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b395edd09d60c9a17340f48021453b45)*

---

> creating a service table just to auto increment a value seems less than ideal for me. – Mohamed Mufeed

> This table is extremely tiny - you may delete all records except one per group with largest autoincremented value in this group anytime. – Akina

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61f0dc36db25dd5f0cf4647d8970cdee

You may schedule excess rows removing (for example, daily) in service event procedure.

Comment: I am using innodb engine. Also, creating a service table just to auto increment a value seems less than ideal for me. I will wait for other answers. Thank you for the support

Comment: @MohamedMufeed *I am using innodb engine* And? nothing prevents to have the tables on multiple engines. *creating a service table just to auto increment a value seems less than ideal for me.* This table is extremely tiny - you may delete all records except one per group with largest autoincremented value in this group anytime.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you

Comment: @MohamedMufeed The fiddle with service table compacting added.